# Slides de imagens em Javascript

Tags: javascript, slider, settimeout

Tudo bem?
Então, tenho um código onde mostro slides de imagens. O código é esse aqui:

```
<script>
    var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();
var slides;

function showSlides() {
    var i;
    slides = document.getElementsByClassName('Containers');
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
       slides[i].style.display = 'none';  
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex> slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = 'block';  
    setTimeout(showSlides, 3500); // Change image every 3,5 seconds
}

function plusSlides(position) {
    slideIndex +=position;
    if (slideIndex> slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
    else if(slideIndex<1){slideIndex = slides.length}
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
       slides[i].style.display = 'none';  
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = 'block';  
}

function currentSlide(index) {
    if (index> slides.length) {index = 1}
    else if(index<1){index = slides.length}
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
       slides[i].style.display = 'none';  
    }
    slides[index-1].style.display = 'block';  
}
</script>
```

Ele possui botões de Ir e Voltar e as imagens passam automaticamente a cada 3,5 segundos. Está tudo ok. O problema é que esse tempo não zera e, quando eu passo as imagens com botão, ela dura apenas o tempo que restava dos 3,5 segundos.
Por exemplo: Se eu olho uma imagem por 2 segundos e passo, com o botão, a próxima só vai durar 1,5 segundo. Como zerar o tempo a cada exibição de imagem?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Quando você chama a função `setTimeout` (ou `setInterval`), o navegador retorna um identificador numérico para o timer a ser executado.
Para evitar que o timer continue quando você manualmente exibe um dos slides (através dos botões), você deve cancelá-lo e criar um novo.
Para cancelar, você deve utilizar o identificador recebido pela pela função `setTimeout` como parâmetro da função `clearTimeout`.

Abaixo um exemplo simples onde essa situação é exemplificada:

```js
botaoIniciar = document.getElementById("iniciar")
botaoParar = document.getElementById("parar")
botaoProximo = document.getElementById("proximo")

let slide = 0;
let timeOutId;
const duracao = 3;


function proximoSlide(){
  slide = slide == 2 ? 0 : ++slide;
  console.log(`Mostrando slide: ${slide}`)
  document.getElementsByClassName("visivel")[0].classList.remove("visivel");
  document.getElementsByClassName("slide")[slide].classList.add("visivel");
}

function proximo(){
  //função executada ao clicar nos botões para exibir o slide
  //abaixo, 'cancela-se' a execução em andamento;
  clearTimeout(timeOutId);
  proximoSlide();
  //abaixo, a função encarregada de iniciar a contagem dos tempos;
  iniciar();
}

function iniciar() {
  console.log("Iniciando timeout...")
  timeOutId = setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(`  Passaram-se ${duracao} segundos.`)
    proximoSlide();
    iniciar();
  }, duracao * 1000);
}

function parar() {
  clearTimeout(timeOutId);
  console.log("Encerrado timeout");
}

botaoIniciar.addEventListener('click', iniciar);
botaoParar.addEventListener('click', parar);
botaoProximo.addEventListener('click', proximo);
```

```css
.slide {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: none;
}

.visivel {
  display: block;
}

.vermelho {
  background-color: red;
}

.amarelo {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.verde {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide vermelho visivel"></div>
<div class="slide amarelo"></div>
<div class="slide verde"></div>

<br>
<button id="iniciar">iniciar timeout</button>
<button id="proximo">proximo slide</button>
<button id="parar">parar timeout</button>
```